# XML deserialize DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an Xml element that needs to contain DateTime of Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec and MS

I later need that that Xml element be casted via XMLDeserializer, to DateTime object.

I know that there are some issues with DateTime Format casting,
My question is what is the DateTime Format that i should write the Xml Element so once i deserialize it via XMLDeserializer i will not have any issues to cast to DateTime object

I would like to have answer like: `{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}` or any other Format that will definatelly work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally `XmlSerializer` uses `XmlConvert` which converts `DateTime` using following format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzzzzz
```

Anyway use ISO 8601 format. In .NET you can use `o` format specifier:

```
dateTime.ToString("o")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. what I did is I created an object of the class and assign value to date time property. Then I serialized the object to get the XML out put. This helped me to find out in what form I should give date time field in my XML document that has to be DE serialized.

It was expecting date filed in below.

2017-06-21T00:00:00+05:30